# NPC crea un archivo en lugar de un directorio

Tags: nodejs, mkdir

Cuál es la razón por la que npc crea un archivo `.ebextensions.` en lugar de una carpeta `.ebextensions.`

Intento usar excec y mkdir simples `.ebextensions.` Comando y no funciona.

```js
ncp('package.config', './build/.ebextensions./.', function (err) {
 if (err) {
  return console.error(err);
 }
 console.log('API copied');
});
```

Modulo https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el link del package que estás usando?

Comment: ¿Por qué simplemente no usas `fs.mkdirSync`?

Comment: Ya coloque el link, @GustavoGarcía no sabia de eso pero investigare y probare jeje

Comment: @GustavoGarcía use tu solucion y funciono si quieres postea como respuesta

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas instalar un paquete para crear directorios en Node.js. La API para interactuar con el sistema de archivos anfritrión es bastante completa. Por ejemplo, para crear un directorio te basta usar la función [`FileSystem#mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback) o si quieres crearlo síncronamente, [`FileSystem#mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode).

**Asíncrona**

```
fs.mkdir('.ebextensions./', function (err) {
  if (err) { ... }
  
  // correcto
});
```

**Síncrona**

```
try {
  fs.mkdirSync('.ebextensions./');

  // correcto
} catch (e) {
  ...
}
```

---

#### Actualización

> Gracias a @Trauma por notar que requieres crear directorios anidados.

Primero, ten en cuenta que el paquete [NCP](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp) (Node Copy Package) tiene como funcionalidad la copia de archivos y directorios. Según tu pregunta, parece que indicas que requieres **crear**.

**Copia de archivos**

Puedes copiar un archivo usando solamente la API de Node.js. Sin embargo, si la complejidad aumenta, es mejor usar un paquete que sea exclusivamente para eso.

```
let source = 'C:/Users/Gustavo/Pictures/bug-hero.svg';
let target = 'D:/ABC/images';
let parts = target.split('/');
let filename = source.split('/').reverse()[0];

parts.forEach((part, i) => {
  if (i > 0) {
    const path = `${parts[i - 1]}/${part}`;
    
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(path);
    }
  } else {
    if (!fs.existsSync(part)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(part);
    }
  }
});

fs
  .createReadStream(source)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${target}/${filename}`));
```

El código anterior copia una imagen **y crea directorios si estos no existen**; lo mismo que hace NCP. Primero se va comprobando directorio por directorio, en caso no exista, lo crea. Finalmente, abrimos un **stream de lectura** desde el archivo o directorio fuente y lo enlazamos con un **stream de escritura** del directorio destino. Como puedes ver son solo unas cuantas líneas; nada fuera de lo normal.

Comment: Creo que lo que pretende, al usar `npc`, es poder crear directorios *de forma recursiva*; es decir, crear **todos los directorios hijos necesarios** hasta llegar al último. No hay API para eso, aunque sea relativamente simple el hacerlo *a mano*.

Comment: Lo que dices, @Trauma, no lo veo en su código. En ese caso, le haría un ejemplo a mano que no es nada del otro mundo. Supongo que es lo que quiere ya que me dijo que pusiera mi comentario como respuesta. Será cosa de esperar a ver qué dice.

Comment: Al indicar './build/.ebextensions./.' y preguntar el porqué crea un archivo y no un directorio, usando `NPC`, que sirve precisamente para eso. He visto en sus comentarios que le sirvió tu respuesta, así que nada que añadir. Borraré estos comentarios dentro de un rato.

Comment: @Trauma, el paquete es `ncp` y es muy usado para **copia** de archivos y directorios; al menos hasta donde yo sé. Pero para creación jerárquica, no tengo idea. De todos modos, en un momento actualizaré mi respuesta en base a ello.

Comment: PD: No borres tus comentarios para que sirvan de referencia.

Comment: @Trauma, respuesta actualizada. No he tenido mucho tiempo, pero el código creo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Mucho *mas mejor* así ;-) +1

Comment: @Trauma ¿Más mejor? jejeje